# How can I apply the LIMIT statement in a SQLite query to a specific side of a join?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here's my requirement:

I have 2 tables, `orders` and `orderContents`. For each row in the `orders` table, there are a certain number of rows that contain description of the order. `id` column serves as foreign key.

What I want is to get all the details for each order (details from `orderContents`, including `id` column from `orders` table) table, but limit no. of results based on common column (foreign key, `id`)

Problem is that it limits `orderContents` rows, instead of limiting `order` rows.

How can I achieve desired effect?

**EDIT:** Updating tables and desired result set

**Orders** table:

[image]

**OrderContents** table:

[image]

**Desired result** on limiting number of records to 2:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the schema you are using?

Comment: We need to see what you've tried so far, as well as what DBMS you're running on.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear in what you are asking. Maybe show a sample of the inputs and expected outputs of your query?

Comment: @Nik : updated with tables and desired result...

Comment: @JohnFx : updated with tables and desired result...I'am using SQLite

Comment: That example made it even more confusing to me. You want the frist 3 rows of the Ordercontents table and whatever it is linked to from the orders table? That query doesn't seem very useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to say that you want the results from both tables but only for the first X orders. If so, try this:

```
SELECT OC.*, O.* FROM OrderContents OC
INNER JOIN  (SELECT * 
             FROM Orders 
             ORDER BY ID 
             LIMIT 2) O ON O.ID=OC.ID
```

Comment: Since the user tagged this as sqllite, shouldn't that be `SELECT * from Orders LIMIT 2`?

Comment: How can I get the backwards solution to this? This solution will include OrderContents without a corresponding Order but it will not include Orders that have no OrderContents. I want all the OrderContents for the first 3 Orders for example but I want the inner join to be done in the other direction.

Comment: Found answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64595522/9563170