# Implementing LIMIT against rows of single table while using LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sqlite, left-join, sql-limit

Given a fairly stereotypical scenario with an item table referenced by an images table holding multiple images for the same item, I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve a ***specific** number of **items***, while collecting ***all** of the **image** rows*.

The setup is trivial, and looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  id  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  ...
  ...
)

CREATE TABLE images (
  item_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  url     STRING,
  ...
  ...
)
```

`LIMIT 20` clamps the maximum number of rows in the entire result set, and incidentally truncates mid-way through an item record.

I'm currently doing two queries, but besides being architecturally not at all ideal, it's practically proving quite awkward to coordinate (which makes a lot of sense since I'm definitely doing it wrong). I'm not finding any info on how to coordinate `LIMIT` with `LEFT JOIN`s, so I thought I'd ask. Thanks!

NB. Similar questions to this do indeed exist, but are asking how to do things like retrieving eg the first (say) 5 images for each item. I'm looking to retrieve (say) 10 items and get all the images for each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A query like:

```
SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY ? LIMIT 10
```

will return 10 rows (at most) from `items`.
You need to provide the column(s) for the `ORDER BY` clause if you have some specific sorting condition in mind.
If not then remove the `ORDER BY` clause, but in this case nothing guarantees the resultset that you will get.

So all you have to do is `LEFT` join the above query to `images`:

```
SELECT it.*, im.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY ? LIMIT 10) it
LEFT JOIN images im
ON im.item_id = it.id
```

Comment: TIL about subqueries today :). After asking the question last night I vaguely wondered if exactly what you describe was possible, but it would likely have taken me a while to arrive here without help (particularly that subqueries must be named in order to work... didn't initially include the `it` at the end of `FROM ()...`, haha). I also incidentally happened to have an `ORDER BY` on my query, bu thanks for letting me know of its criticality in this type of situation.